# Modifying the json response - WEbAPI

Tags: json

I am returning the object directly in the GET request as following.

```
Ok(object);
and the response json is given as,
json data-->
{
"id":"1",
"name":"testname"
}
```

I want to add some more details to this json
-->

```
{
success:"true",
messageDetails:"The response is returned by the service",
data:{}
}
```

how to accomplish this?
can i club all the things in Ok(object) ??

Comment: In which programming language? Show us your code.

Comment: what is Ok(object)?

Comment: This is GET method for ASP.NET WebAPI framwork.


public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
          List<Employee> list = GetEmployee();
           if (list != null)
                return Ok(list);
            else
                return NotFound();
        }

Comment: @AmeyDeshpande edit this into your question please - code in comments is hard to read and people might miss it. And tag the question with .Net and Web API

Comment: to answer your question, if you want to include this data, the easiest way is to make a generic wrapper class with those properties, with "data" as an object, and then return that object, passing your "list" in the "data" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), for example:

```
object data = new { id = 1, name = "testname" };

return Ok(new
{
    success = "true",
    messageDetails = "The response is returned by the service",
    data
});
```

Comment: i created a wrapper class and passed the same in Ok method.
use of anonymous types is also working. thanks!!